# Swift constructor not appearing in list of methods, "Arguments passed to call that takes no arguments"

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a beginner in `Swift`. I tried creating a simple class that represents a `Meal`.

It has some properties and a constructor that returns an optional

[image]

But when I try to test it, or instantiate it anywhere, all I get is an error. Can't seem to figure out what is going on.

[image]

Comment: On first glance it looks good. What happens if you (1) comment/delete out the line *and* rebuild things, then (2) let code-completion do the work?

Comment: Have you tried doing the usual rigamarole of clearing your build folder, restarting xcode, etc?

Comment: @dfd Thanks, everything is working now.

Comment: Btw, you can repalce `rating >= 0 && rating <= 5` with just `(0...5).contains(rating)` or equivalently  `0...5 ~= rating`

Comment: I've found the on occasion when making class changes such as this where things reside in separate files those changes don't take. As @Alexander said, maybe a simple clean (or clean build folder) does the trick. Whatever, glad you fixed the issue.

Comment: @dfd A kind of related question. I usually get errors in my code (e.g. like "Arguments passed to call that contains no...") But these errors don't seem to get immediately updated by the editor even after changing them. Is there any tips you can give me on how to force a reload/reinterpretation by the editor?

Comment: When you build the project, does the screen flash "Build succeeded"? I've noticed that old, irrelevant error messages can stick around, but if I get the "Build succeeded" popup then the build has in fact succeeded.

Comment: I've had a few times (usually in large projects with a few dozen files) that Xcode successfully builds a project but error are still listed - and closing/reopening clears it up. More often, as @BallpointBen said, a successful build clears them up. This started with Xcode 9, and IMO is restricted to Swift projects. I know *a lot* of "real-time" build error improvements went into Xcode 9 and chalk this ups to those improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code above, you have to explicitly declare your class **public** for you to be able to instantiate it in another file. The default access type when you do not specify any access control is **internal** in swift.

I have done the below modification to your code.

import UIKit

public class MealModel {

```
let name: String
let photo: UIImage?
let rating: Int

public init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, rating: Int) {

    guard !name.isEmpty, (rating >= 0) && (rating <= 5) else { return nil }

    self.name = name
    self.photo = photo
    self.rating = rating
}
```

}

I believe this will fix your problem.